# Power Series of the Principal Branch of Logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

How would I go about determining the power series expansion for the principal branch of $\log$ about $z = i$?  I would assume I should start from $\frac{1}{z}$, but I don't know how to manipulate this into a power series centered at $z= i$.

Comment: $z = i + (z-i) = i(1 - i(z-i))$

Comment: ... = i*sum i(z-i)^k ?  Not sure how to format the comments

Comment: You use the same MathJax formatting in comments as in questions/answers (be careful with newlines, however, typing a newline in a comment submits). The method to get the power series with centre $i$ is practically the same as for the power series with centre $1$.